# Is It possible to get permission for photo deletion when the application is installed

Tags: ios

I am deleting pictures from the Photo Library using Photo Framework. When I try to delete a photo it asks for permission. Is it possible that I could get permission from the user when the app is installed?

Comment: Permission is asked for when you attempt to use the resource.   Use it early to get permission early.  You can't ask at install, but you could when they first launch the app.   Just be aware that it may frighten away users to get bombarded with a stream of allow this/allow that sort of thing.   This was a good take on how to do it... http://techcrunch.com/2014/04/04/the-right-way-to-ask-users-for-ios-permissions/

Comment: and how i can ask for permission at launch time ?

Comment: Simply try to access the resource.   Add a bit of code to app delegate to access photos (may have to create and then delete a temp photo to get full access permission).   The access attempt turns into a request for permission.   If you later detect the permission is missing you can pop them over to settings to fix it.   (search SO for exactly how to do it.. its been answered)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No -- Apple asks for permission on your behalf when you call an API that requires it.